# Pipe image from python to C++ and back

Tags: python, c++, opencv, pipe

I need to read an image (with OpenCV) in Python, pipe it to a C++ program and then pipe it back to Python. 
This is my code so far:

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cstdio>

#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *fifo_name = "fifo";
    mknod(fifo_name, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
    ifstream f(fifo_name);
    string line;
    getline(f, line);
    auto data_size = stoi(line);

    char *buf = new char[data_size];
    f.read(buf, data_size);

    Mat matimg;
    matimg = imdecode(Mat(1, data_size, CV_8UC1, buf), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    imshow("display", matimg);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Python**

```
import os
import cv2

fifo_name = 'fifo'

def main():
    data = cv2.imread('testimage.jpg').tobytes()
    try:
        os.mkfifo(fifo_name)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    with open(fifo_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(len(data)).encode())
        f.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

An exception is thrown when C++ tries to print to image. I have debugged the code and `buf` is filled, but `matimg` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

In the code, the C++ reader calls `mknod`, whereas it should just open an existing named pipe created by the Python writer.

If the pipe doesn't exists when the reader tries to open it, it can either fail or keep re-trying to open the named pipe with a timeout. E.g.:

```
const char *fifo_name = "fifo";
std::ifstream f;
for(;;) { // Wait till the named pipe is available.
    f.open(fifo_name, std::ios_base::in);
    if(f.is_open())
        break;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
}
```

Comment: The read is successful. I have written the contents of `buf` in a file and its output matches python's output to the pipe. The problem is that `imdecode` does not decode the image succesfully.